# How to incorporate two seperate c++ files into one program?

Tags: c++, dev-c++

I am new to C++ and I have a small question.
I have been trying to get two files to operate within each other by using the goto function to try to jump from one place in one file to the other. This is not working, obviously, and I want to know the proper way to do it.
P.S. I remembered to use the #include "filename.cpp" function as well.

Comment: You should try to write a header file for one of the files and then include that header file in the other .cpp file

Comment: You should not include .cpp files. It can cause compilation problems when you have mutual inclusion. Use header files instead.

And don't forget to add all the files to your compilation line.

Comment: NOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOooo!  Please no `goto`.  Please use a function call.  If you're using gcc, then you just need to list both .cpp files on the command line to get them to compile together: `g++ -o myprog myfile1.cpp myfile2.cpp`.

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying to do is most likely possible,  but it is much MORE likely the wrong way to do it, especially since you say you are new to C++

Try not to use goto for this at all.    Use functions.

Comment: And my apologies if this feels like it isn't solving your problem at all.   But in a week you'll see what I mean :)

Comment: I would +1 this but you didn't answer the question. The question was not 'is goto a good idea' but 'why doesn't doing ... work' and the answer involves using headers in the include and checking that the command line includes both files when using the compiler.

Comment: fair enough :)   thought this would be more helpful for him long term.